# Enable audit that will go in specific tablespace

Tags: database, oracle, audit

I need to enable audit for my database with those specifications:

1. All audit and indexes has to go in newly created tablespace
2. It
   has to show login/logoff for all users
3. It has to show all
   SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE that users done

I tried to do it like (doesn't work):

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET audit_trail=db SCOPE=SPFILE;
SHUTDOWN
STARTUP
audit alter system by access;
AUDIT CREATE PROCEDURE
AUDIT CREATE TABLESPACE
audit insert, update, delete on something by hr by session whenever not successful;
audit something view by somebody by access whenever successful;
AUDIT ROLE;
AUDIT READ ON DIRECTORY ext_dir;

CREATE TABLESPACE SYSAUD
DATAFILE ' SYSAUD_01.dat'
SIZE 1G
AUTOEXTEND ON
ONLINE;

exec DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.SET_AUDIT_TRAIL_LOCATION(AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE=>DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_AUD_STD,AUDIT_TRAIL_LOCATION_VALUE => 'SYSAUD') ;

AUDIT SELECT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE BY ACCESS;
```

But that doesn't really seems to work for me, and I am not sure how can I check audits. If I write:

```
 Select * from SYSAUD
```

I can't see anything.

As I had copy of database I rollback all commands and now I have to do it from beginning. But I am not sure what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`SYSAUD` is a tablespace, a storage location, not a table. To see the Audit trail you select from `SYS.AUD$` .

Comment: Yeah I got that latter, do You maybe know how can I implement audit on login/logoff and SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE for all users?